# how can I do reproducible benchmarks in a storage system?

Tags: filesystems, memcached, storage, benchmarking

If the memory of the machine is far larger than the cache configured for a storage system, the file system caches far more data than the cache configured for the storage system. so, how to do reproducible benchmarks with different machine memory and the same cache configured for the storage system?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running a program that allocates and locks a bunch of memory  (i.e. pin it so it can't be paged out), then sleeps.  Kill it when you want to release the memory.

Specifically, I'm thinking of [the `mlock(2)` POSIX system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html), or the Linux-specific [`MAP_LOCKED` flag for `mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).  This requires root, since the default `ulimit -l` is only 64kiB for non-root users, at least on my Ubuntu desktop.

---

On an otherwise-idle system with nothing using much memory, it should be easy to detect the total present and lock all but 2GB of it, for example.  It's probably less easy to choose a reasonable size to lock on systems with other processes running and using varying amounts of RAM.